# Wordpress - customising the_excerpt() not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added the following code to my functions.php script within my theme:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 15;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

as suggested on this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt

but the length of the excerpt is still the default 55 words and the string at the end is still `[...]` rather than `...`.

Wordpress version is 3.4.1

The code I am using to display the excerpt is simply:

```
the_excerpt();
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it so that the additions to my functions.php work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code for limit the content

```
<?php query_posts('cat=ID'.'&showposts=NO. OF POST') ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,65).' [...]'; ?></p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More...</a>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve the desired result by using something along the lines of:

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$excerpt = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($excerpt, 0, 71));
echo '<div class="blog-posts-grid-box-excerpt">' . $excerpt . '...</div>';
```

Hopefully this is some use to someone who discovers this question.